# Byobu reports different numbers from system monitor for network usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

Why are the numbers that byobu reports for my network usage different from system monitor?

[image]

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that it's off by about a factor of 8...

Byobu, by default, is reporting "kbps", or kilobits per second, or 1000 bits per second.  I chose that as the default reporting rate to match what other network device data rates are typically reported in (like 10mbps/100mbps/1Gbps ethernet, 11Mbps/54Mbps wireless).

Your network monitor is reporting KiB/s, which is kibibytes per second, or 1024 bytes per second.

You can trivially configure Byobu's network reporting unit by setting `NETWORK_UNITS=bytes` in your `~/.byobu/statusrc`.